# Возведение в степень C++

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я уже пару раз сегодня просил помощи и вот что получилось. Программа должна выполнять возведение в степень длинных чисел. Число и степень записаны в string.  Проблема - возведение вроде и работает, но рандомно, в прямом смысле слова. При степени больше 10 иногда считает верно, а иногда вообще некорректные значения. Например, при a=25 и n=30 программа должна вывести 867361737988403547205962240695953369140625, а выводит 9607807733118534088134765625. При a=2555555555 и n=25 выводятся вообще какие-то символы и цифры случайные... Кракозябры выводятся при вводе большого основания. Например 132^1000 считает верно. Также неверно считает и 13265563353646646453454^165, но если взять значения поменьше, то все отлично. Проверяю с помощью вольфрамальфа. Я уже не знаю с чего начать, вообще не могу установить закономерность проблемы. Прошу помощи, очень надо, осталось совсем немного доработать!!! Спасибо.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;
 char A[100000000],B[100], C[10000000000];
 long long int length;
void DeleteNull(string &str){
    int i = 0;
    while(str[i] == '0'|| str[i] < '0' || str [i] > '9')
        i++;
    str.erase(0,i);
}
void inc(string &s){
    int l = s.length();
    bool state = true;
    for(int i = l-1; state && i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (state) 
            s[i]++;
        if (state = (s[i] > '9')) 
            s[i] = '0';
    }
    if (state) 
        s = '1' + s;
}
void Umnoj(string &a, string &temp, int size){
    temp="";
    for (int ix = 0; ix < length+100; ix++){
        C[ix] = 0;
        A[ix] = 0;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
        A[i]=a[a.size()-i-1]-'0';
    length += size+1;   
    for (int ix = 0; ix < a.size(); ix++)
        for (int jx = 0; jx < size; jx++)
            C[ix + jx] += A[ix] * B[jx];
    for (int ix = 0; ix < length-1; ix++)
    {
        C[ix + 1] +=  C[ix] / 10;
        C[ix] %= 10;
    }
    while (C[length] == 0)
        length-- ;
    for(int i=length; i>-1; i--)
        temp+=C[i]+'0';//перевод числа в string
    DeleteNull(temp);//удаление всякого мусора перед числом
    a=temp;
}
int main()
{
    string a,n,t,count="1",temp;
    int size;   
    // cin>>a;
    // cin>>n;
    a="13444645";//основание
    n="30";//степень
    size=a.size();
    temp=a;
    length=size;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        B[i]=a[a.size()-i-1]-'0';
    while(n.compare(count)!=0){     
        inc(count);
        Umnoj(a,temp,size);
    }
    cout<<a<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");    
}
```

Comment: А почему у вас массивы А С только 100 символов очищаются?.. Там побольше надо.

Comment: Там переменная length в которой накапливается длина числа + 100 символов на запас.

Comment: А кстати, если вы умножите число знаков 20, то у вас в массив C пойдёт сумма 20 пар умножений однозначных чисел... Короче в char не влезет точно. Замените на int.

Comment: Да, заменил на long long int, занчения расширились, но не до конца, если ввести огромное число, ситуация аналогично. Другая проблема в неправильном подсчете самом: мелкие значения считает отлично, если вводить очень большие, то неправильный ответ вообще.

Comment: Попробуйте переделать само умножение 2-х чисел. Храните перенос и сразу пишите в результат правильную цифру.

Answer (score 1):

Значит, так. Чтоб закрыть тему - бегом набросал умножение, сложение и возведение в степень. Только - набросано за полчаса, вроде работает, но кое-где веревочками перевязано :) - типа нормализации после умножения вместо корректного расписывания переносов.

Об оптимальности говорить не приходится :( Тем не менее вроде работает.

Только консультаций по тому, что делает та или иная строчка кода, простите, но - не будет. Разбирайтесь сами. Числа храню для простоты в виде кусков по 9 цифр.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class superLong
{
public:
    using ullong = unsigned long long;
    superLong(ullong x = 0) { d.push_back(x); };
    superLong(string s);
    operator string() const;

    friend superLong operator *(const superLong&a, const superLong&b);
    friend superLong operator +(const superLong&a, const superLong&b);

private:
    vector<ullong> d;
    static constexpr ullong max = 1000000000ull;
};


superLong operator *(const superLong&a, const superLong&b)
{
    superLong r;
    for(size_t i = 0, e = a.d.size(); i < e; ++i)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0, f = b.d.size(); j < f; ++j)
        {
            superLong::ullong v = a.d[i]*b.d[j];
            superLong::ullong carry = v/superLong::max;
            v = v%superLong::max;
            if (i+j >= r.d.size()) r.d.resize(i+j+1,0);
            r.d[i+j] += v;
            if (carry)
            {
                if (i+j+1 >= r.d.size()) r.d.resize(i+j+2,0);
                r.d[i+j+1] += carry;
            }
        }
    }
    for(size_t i = 0, e = r.d.size(); i < e-1; ++i)
    {
        if (r.d[i] > superLong::max)
        {
            r.d[i+1] += r.d[i] / superLong::max;
            r.d[i] %= superLong::max;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

superLong operator +(const superLong&a, const superLong&b)
{
    superLong d((a.d.size() > b.d.size()) ? a : b);
    superLong c((a.d.size() > b.d.size()) ? b : a);
    c.d.resize(d.d.size(),0);
    superLong::ullong carry = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < d.d.size(); ++i)
    {
        d.d[i] += c.d[i]+carry;
        carry = d.d[i]/superLong::max;
        d.d[i] %= superLong::max;
    }
    if (carry) d.d.push_back(carry);
    return d;
}

superLong::superLong(string s)
{
    superLong q;
    int len = s.length()%9;
    if (len)
    {
        string val = s.substr(0,len);
        s = s.substr(len,s.length()-len);
        q = stoll(val);
    }
    while (s.length())
    {
        string val = s.substr(0,9);
        s = s.substr(9,s.length()-9);
        q = q * superLong::max + stoll(val);
    }
    d = std::move(q.d);
}

superLong::operator string() const
{
    string s;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < d.size(); ++i)
    {
        char buf[12];
        snprintf(buf,12,"%09lld",d[i]);
        s = buf + s;
    }
    return s;
}

superLong superPow(superLong x, unsigned long long p)
{
    superLong r(1);
    while(p)
    {
        if (p&0x01) r = r * x;
        p >>= 1;
        x = x*x;
    }
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    superLong l1("111111111111111111111253672373");
    superLong l2("552345678012345678012898234897");
    cout << string(l1*l2) << endl<<endl;;
    cout << string(superPow(2,1000)) << endl;
}
```

Comment: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/fft_multiply http://e-maxx.ru/algo/big_integer ссылки по теме.

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но вот я только начал изучать с++, векторы и классы мы даже не проходили еще, так что ну скопирую я код - толку ноль для меня. Мне бы мой довести до ума, совсем немного осталось. Надо только разобраться, почему иногда происходит неправильный подсчет!. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Мне кажется, что у меня ошибка в подсчете переменной length

Answer (score 1):

Вы приняли правильное решение хранить сомножители с обратным порядком цифр.

Однако, мне кажется, что просто умножение 2-х чисел лучше запрограммировать более очевидным способом, сразу записывая в результат правильную цифру и запоминая перенос.

```
/* 
   Умножение целых десятичных чисел без знака
   c = a * b
   a[], b[] содержат значимые цифры чисел в обратном порядке
   (старшие цифры числа справа), 
   la -- количество цифр в a[]
   lb -- количество цифр в b[]
   Результат получается в массиве c[], 
   под который в вызывающем коде должно быть выделено достатчно памяти (la + lb)
   Возвращает количество значимых цифр в результате
*/
int
mult (char a[], int la, char b[], int lb, char c[])
{
  int cc = 0,     // цифра переноса
    lc = la + lb; // максимальное количество значимых цифр результата


  for (int i = 0; i < lc; i++)
    c[i] = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < la; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < lb; j++) {
      int r = c[i + j] + cc + a[i] * b[j];
      c[i + j] = r % 10;
      cc = r / 10;
    }
    c[i + lb] = cc;
    cc = 0;
  }

  return c[lc - 1] ? lc : lc - 1;
}
```

Попробуйте модифицировать свой код умножения таким же образом и думаю, что все будет работать.

Очевидно, что все промежуточные умножения при вычислении степени можно делать именно с таким представлением чисел, т.е. переводить обратно в строку только окончательный результат.

**Update**

Вот пример вычислений степени (с показателем степени оперирую в `int`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int
mult (char a[], int la, char b[], int lb, char c[])
{
   ....
}

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  string s = av[1] ? av[1] : "123";
  int p = av[1] && av[2] ? atoi(av[2]) : 2;

  if (p < 1) {
    cout << "invalid power: " << p << '\n';
    return 1;
  }
  int i, j, l = s.size(), lr = l;
  char a[l];
  for (i = l - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; --i)
    if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
      a[j++] = s[i] - '0';
    else {
      cout << "invalid number: " << s << '\n';
      return 1;
    }

  char b[l * p + 1], r[l * p + 2];
  cout << s << " ** " << p << " = ";

  memcpy(b, a, l);
  while (--p) {
    lr = mult(a, l, b, lr, r);
    if (p > 1)
      memcpy(b, r, lr);
  }

  for (i = 0, j = lr - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    r[i] += '0';
    char t = r[j] + '0';
    r[j] = r[i];
    r[i] = t;
  }
  if (i == j)
    r[i] += '0';
  r[lr] = 0;

  cout << r << '\n';
}
```

Comment: не получается интегрировать ваш кусок кода в мой метод, лишний значения выводятся какие-то

Comment: @Maxitt, ну, как легко встроить вызов `mult()` в ваш код, сходу не придумал. Написал в **update** ответа свой пример.