# Как умножить длинное число на длинное число?

Tags: c++

Нужно написать программу, которая вычиcляла бы факториал больше 13. Сам по себе алгоритм нахождения факториала понятен. А как умножать длинные числа?

Comment: Недавно уже отвечал на [подобный вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596520/232) (только там возводили в степень)

Comment: Ну, до 20! включительно потянет `long long`...

Comment: Есть много ресурсов на эту тему. Например, этот http://e-maxx.ru/algo/big_integer или этот http://zealcomputing.ru/besedy/013/

Comment: @Roma Mikov  Почитате по этой ссылке http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000047-000-0-0-1475597138 Там среди прочего найдете про факториал, и сколько значений факториала может содержать тот или иной целочисленный тип в C++.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример вычисления 1000!:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class superLong
{
public:
    using ullong = unsigned long long;
    superLong(ullong x = 0) { d.push_back(x); };
    superLong(string s);
    operator string() const;

    friend superLong operator *(const superLong&a, const superLong&b);
    friend superLong operator +(const superLong&a, const superLong&b);

private:
    vector<ullong> d;
    static constexpr ullong max = 1000000000ull;
};


superLong operator *(const superLong&a, const superLong&b)
{
    superLong r;
    for(size_t i = 0, e = a.d.size(); i < e; ++i)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0, f = b.d.size(); j < f; ++j)
        {
            superLong::ullong v = a.d[i]*b.d[j];
            superLong::ullong carry = v/superLong::max;
            v = v%superLong::max;
            if (i+j >= r.d.size()) r.d.resize(i+j+1,0);
            r.d[i+j] += v;
            if (carry)
            {
                if (i+j+1 >= r.d.size()) r.d.resize(i+j+2,0);
                r.d[i+j+1] += carry;
            }
        }
    }
    for(size_t i = 0, e = r.d.size(); i < e-1; ++i)
    {
        if (r.d[i] > superLong::max)
        {
            r.d[i+1] += r.d[i] / superLong::max;
            r.d[i] %= superLong::max;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

superLong operator +(const superLong&a, const superLong&b)
{
    superLong d((a.d.size() > b.d.size()) ? a : b);
    superLong c((a.d.size() > b.d.size()) ? b : a);
    c.d.resize(d.d.size(),0);
    superLong::ullong carry = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < d.d.size(); ++i)
    {
        d.d[i] += c.d[i]+carry;
        carry = d.d[i]/superLong::max;
        d.d[i] %= superLong::max;
    }
    if (carry) d.d.push_back(carry);
    return d;
}

superLong::superLong(string s)
{
    superLong q;
    int len = s.length()%9;
    if (len)
    {
        string val = s.substr(0,len);
        s = s.substr(len,s.length()-len);
        q = stoll(val);
    }
    while (s.length())
    {
        string val = s.substr(0,9);
        s = s.substr(9,s.length()-9);
        q = q * superLong::max + stoll(val);
    }
    d = std::move(q.d);
}

superLong::operator string() const
{
    string s;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < d.size(); ++i)
    {
        char buf[12];
        snprintf(buf,12,"%09lld",d[i]);
        s = buf + s;
    }
    return s;
}

superLong superPow(superLong x, unsigned long long p)
{
    superLong r(1);
    while(p)
    {
        if (p&0x01) r = r * x;
        p >>= 1;
        x = x*x;
    }
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    superLong f = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= 1000; ++i)
    {
        f = f * i;
    }
    cout << string(f) << endl;
}
```